# How to convert Intptr to ImageSharp Image in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, imagesharp

In c# (Windows), with the `width`, `height` and `stride` of an image, we can convert an `Intptr` to `Bitmap` as follows:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, intptrImage);
```

But `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is no longer available on `Linux` and we have to use `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image`.
How do I convert an `Intptr` to an image using `ImageSharp`?

Comment: can you show the code, where `intptrImage` is initialized / comes from?

Comment: This `intptrImage` comes from an image processing library. This is the part of the photo where the license plate was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
// copy data to byte array
var size = height * stride;
var managedArray = new byte[size];
Marshal.Copy(intptrImage, managedArray, 0, size);

var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.LoadPixelData<Bgr24>(managedArray,width, height);
```

This solution works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).